# BottomNavigationView reloading fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation-graph

I have implemented BottomNavigationView with NavController but fragments keep reloading on each click, even with the new navigation library update. I also tried setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener but it doesn't trigger anything. What am I doing wrong ?
I know this question have been asked more than once but I feel like I tried them all and none of them work. I was hoping I could avoid reverting my code with old libraries or using boilerplate solutions.
Here is my code :

> build.gradle (:app)

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
```

> HomeActivity.kt

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
Serializable {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
private lateinit var navController: NavController
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding= ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.home_container) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController
    binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController) 
    }
    }
```

> activity_home.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/home_container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar_layout"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_container"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> nav_main.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.projectName.ui.main.ContactsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contacts" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.projectName.SearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/search"
        tools:layout="@layout/search_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:name="com.projectName.ui.main.NotificationsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/notifications_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fourthFragment"
        android:name="com.projectName.chat.ChatFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_page" />
</navigation>
```

> bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_contacts_24"
        android:title=""
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications_none_24"
        android:title=""
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fourthFragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_white_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
</menu>
```

> Fragments

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = NotificationsFragment()
    }
    private lateinit var viewModel: NotificationsViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotificationsViewModel::class.java)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.notifications_fragment, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```

I also gave every layout an ID like the document of savedInstateState suggests.

Thank you.

> EDIT

I could not find a solution for my problem so I used BottomNavigationView with ViewPager2 :

> HomePagerAdapter.kt

```
private val TAB_TITLES = arrayOf(
    Constants.CONTACTS,
    Constants.SEARCH,
    Constants.NOTIFICATIONS,
    Constants.CHATS
)

class HomePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = TAB_TITLES.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return if (getPageTitle(position) == Constants.CONTACTS) {
            ContactsFragment.newInstance()
        } else if (getPageTitle(position) == Constants.SEARCH) {
            SearchFragment.newInstance()
        } else if (getPageTitle(position) == Constants.NOTIFICATIONS) {
            NotificationsFragment.newInstance()
        } else {
            ChatsFragment.newInstance()
        }
    }

    private fun getPageTitle(position: Int): String {
        return TAB_TITLES[position]
    }
}
```

> HomeActivity.kt

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
    Serializable, SearchFragment.OnPersonSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    val homePagerAdapter = HomePagerAdapter(this)
    val viewPager: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.home_view_pager)
    viewPager.adapter = homePagerAdapter
    viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
    viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
    viewPager.overScrollMode = ViewPager2.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

    findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        .setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.firstFragment -> {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false)
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.secondFragment -> {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false)
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.thirdFragment -> {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false)
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.fourthFragment -> {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, false)
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> return@setOnItemSelectedListener false
            }

            }
}
}
```

> activity_home.xml

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar_layout"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_view_pager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, you want that whenever you change from one fragment to another by using the bottom navigation bar that the fragments will perserve their state. I think this might be helpful https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/multi-back-stacks. Every tab on the bottom navigation will have its own graph and while switching from one tab to another the state will be saved. Let me know if this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you, I tried your link but my fragments keep reloading on each bottom bar click...

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate on "the fragment is reloading"? Are you doing an api call or what is going in those screens?

Comment: The fragments states are not saved, all the data load again like it was the first time loading it. I used Log in the fragments lifecycle to see what happens and the fragments are completely recreated on every click on the bottom bar except from the first page who has the good behavior and do not reload. I don't understand why because it's pretty much the same as the three others pages of the navigation bar

Comment: Did you create also 3 nested nav graphs and used them for every tab on the bottom navigation bar? This is strange because as far as I remember the state should persist. Do you mind trying again and take in consideration the following: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f 
Alternatively, you could create a cache mechanism database or something similar and refresh the data on swipe etc.

Comment: I tried your link before, I retried but it's still the same output.. I think I am just gonna go with the old libraries